# pandas - insert values from one data frame into another

Tags: pandas

[image of two dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz04s.jpg)
[image]

I would like to add to create the column new_column with the corresponding values from the second data frame.

[desired outcome - but with matching values in column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC01K.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Please post text rather than images, also I think this should work:  `df['new_column'] = other_df['Equity(24 AAPL)']`

Comment: Please follow: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was struggling on how to explain my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_sp_500_long = pd.melt(df_sp_500_long.reset_index(), 
                         id_vars='date', var_name='symbol', 
                         value_name='new_column')

(first_df
 .reset_index()
 .merge(df_sp_500_long, on=['date','symbol'], how='left'))
```